# How do I compile a userspace application for a particular Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, userspace

I have a Linux kernel source. I am building Linux kernel image from that source. Now, I have a userspace application. How do I compile the userspace application for that particular Linux kernel source?

Comment: Do you mean driver? Usually you don't build an userspace application for a given kernel but for a given `libc` and architecture.

Comment: No, not a driver or kernel module, but a normal userspace application. Yes for some `libc` which is there in a particular Linux kernel.